# Is it possible to authenticate against a Sql Db in ADFS 2019?

Tags: adfs

Is it possible to configure the ADFS to use a SQL DB(any database that supports SQL query language) for users instead of the default ActiveDirectory?
(ADFS 2019)

Comment: What is a "SQL Store"? SQL is a query language, so "authenticate against SQL" does not make any sense. You can't authenticate against a language.

Comment: Any database that uses the SQL query language.

Answer (score 1):

Not natively. The way to do it as of today (25/02/2020) is to use a product that does LDAP like a proxy for the SQL database. See https://optimalidm.com/products/virtual-identity-server/.

Then use that LDAP directory like so https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-ad-fs-to-authenticate-users-stored-in-ldap-directories